# Is a class representing a JSON response a DTO, a domain object, or something else?

Tags: java, packages, design-principles, dto, domain-objects

Consider a restful service in Spring MVC. I am wondering how to package my response classes, i.e. how to name the containing package.

First I thought of them as being domain objects. But they are actually a bit different, because they wrap my true domain objects like this:

```
{
    header: {
        // ...
    },
    domainObjectSpecificKey: {
        // domain object properties
    }
}
```

The response class is mapped to the top-level JSON object. So then I thought they may be DTOs actually -- but as far as I understand DTOs are used between application layers, and not for "output" objects to be used between separate applications.

So my questions is: does this kind of object have a special name? If yes, what's that? If not, can we definitely state that it is NOT a DTO or a domain object, i.e. should I name the package differently or can I use the one of that seems better to my liking?

Comment: What is the consumer if not another part of the application? If you consider it like that, it's easy to think of these kinds of objects as DTO's

Comment: It is some other application. A totally different project. In fact, there can be a couple of other apps using this restful service, they are not "one big application".

Comment: Even then, the name "data transfer object" describes its purpose: transferring data (out of your system)

Comment: @AndyBursh, since no-one else seems to be posting other oppinions, if you post your comment as an answer, I'll accept it. Thank you for your thoughts!

Comment: Why don't you simply name your package "response classes?"  The correct name is the one that is most descriptive to you, and you're calling them *response classes.*

Comment: I could, actually, I was just wondering if they fit one of the categories mentioned -- or any other category for that matter.

Answer (score 1):

I would consider a class representing a JSON response to be a Data Contract. Keeping it separate from your DTOs and Domain Objects also keeps the clients consuming your service decoupled from the rest of your system.